# Adding user through bash in MySQL

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

This is my first try to pass a bash command in mysql terminal,
I'm doing this alot:

**creating a dummy user each time I install an app** to interact with the database.

however, all my tries failed, and here is my line of code:

```
new_user(){ mysql -u"$1" -p"$2" -e 'CREATE USER "$3"@"$4" IDENTIFIED BY "$5";
            GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON "$6".* TO "$3"@"$4";
            FLUSH PRIVILEGES; 
            exit;' &&
        echo `new MySQL USER has been created ..
            name:"$3" server:"$4" password:"$5" database:"$6"` ; }
```

however, it is giving me this **error**:

```
 ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
 check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
 for the right syntax to use near '"$4".* TO "$1"@"$2"' at line 1
```

I have tried using the `-e` but as shown with no luck.

how to pass bash variables in mysql?

### Update:

thanks to the comments, I have updated my code for the quotes, however I still cannot pass the variables to mysql terminal.

```
new_user() {
    SQL="CREATE USER\"$3\"@\"$4\" IDENTIFIED BY \"$5\"; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON \"$6\".* TO \"$3\"@\"$4\"; FLUSH PRIVILEGES; exit;"
    mysql -uroot -p1 -e "$SQL" &&
    echo new MySQL USER has been created ..  name:\"$3\" server:\"$4\" password:\"$5\" database:\"$6\"
```

}

Comment: I'm having mysql as alias, so I have udpated the question to be ok with quotes.

Comment: @tadman I have passed all the variables in another 1 like this `new_user() {
        SQL="CREATE USER\"$3\"@\"$4\" IDENTIFIED BY \"$5\"; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON \"$6\".* TO \"$3\"@\"$4\"; FLUSH PRIVILEGES; exit;"
        mysql -uroot -p1 -e "$SQL" &&
        echo new MySQL USER has been created ..  name:\"$3\" server:\"$4\" password:\"$5\" database:\"$6\"
}
` however the variables werent passed to mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid figuring out how to escape what quotes by using [`HEREDOC`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document).

To debug, maybe try breaking your function into two.

```
gen_user_sql(){
  cat <<HEREDOC
   CREATE USER '$1'@'$2' IDENTIFIED BY '$3';
   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $4.* TO '$1'@'$2';
   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

HEREDOC
}
new_user(){
   sqluser="$1"; shift
   sqlpswd="$1"; shift
   mysql -u"$sqluser" -p"$sqlpswd" -e "$(gen_user_sql $@)"
   echo "new user: $@"
}
# see the query
gen_user_sql user host id db
# actually run it
new_user sqlu sqlp user host id db
```

some notes in case there is new syntax:

- `$@` is all the variables passed in. `shift` removes what would be `$1` from `$@`. (after `shift`, `$1` returns what was `$2` before `shift` was called)
- `$(command)` captures the output of `command` and in this case uses it as string input to `mysql`

Comment: awesome explanation, and code .. but there is something i'm still stuck in .. `ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 2: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''database'.* TO 'user'@'localhost'' at line 1` while the user is created; there is no privileges added. is the `;` passed as well in `HEREDOC` like the variables?

Comment: I figured out the problem, I need to adjust 2 lines .. one in $4 not '$4' and the second was exit, It slipped from me that if I'm sending `-e` I dont need to exit as i'm just sending some commands.

Comment: You coul avoid useles fork by using *HEREDOC*  directly with mysql: `mysql -u"$sqluser" -p"$sqlpswd" <<<heremysql`

Comment: @F.Hauri absolutely. And if this is run inside a loop a whole bunch of times the performance hit might be visible.  but the fork isn't entirely useless. abstracting the command into two parts makes interactive debugging (figuring out the quotes and variables) a lot easier. And if you want to have more than one sql generator function, `new_user` could take the generator as an argument: `mysql ... "$($sql_gen_func $@)"`

Comment: @Will if you have to loop over this kind of function, you could look for [*long running* forks](https://github.com/F-Hauri/Connector-bash) to `mysql`!